# <h:outputStylesheet doesn't work within JSF <ui:composition

Tags: css, jsf

Inside my `<ui:composition..>` code block, everything that I try to render with `<h:outputText ..>` tag, does not obey the classes definied in `<h:outputStylesheet  library="css" name="imagens/index.css">`:

Here's my code:

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <ui:define name="conteudoRodape">
       <h:outputStylesheet  library="css" name="imagens/index.css">
           <h:outputText styleClass="centro" value="Acessando como: Filial:" />
       </h:outputStylesheet>
       ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What exactly is your concrete problem? This construct would only cause the nested `h:outputText` not being rendered at all, but the stylesheet itself should be loaded just fine (provided that the library and name are correct). Do you get a 404 on the CSS resource? Or are styles been overridden? Or was all turned into pink? Etc. Please elaborate the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're nesting an h:outputText tag inside h:outputStylesheet, as well as using the library name in the name attribute.  Try changing:

```
<h:outputStylesheet  library="css" name="imagens/index.css">
<h:outputText styleClass="centro" value="Acessando como: Filial:" />
</h:outputStylesheet>
```

to:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css/imagens" name="index.css" />
```

Comment: With regard to the `library` attribute, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: Ahhh yes, thank you : )  Also, his concrete problem was that the h:outputText is not being styled (likely because it is nested)

Comment: No, it wouldn't have appeared in the HTML output at all. That's something entirely different than "style not being obeyed".